# Showing a consequence of definition of internal direct products.

Tags: group-theory

Show that if $G$ is the internal direct product of  $H_1,H_2,\dots ,H_n$ and $i\neq j$ with $1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq n$, then $H_i\cap H_j=\{e\}$.

The definition that I follow is as follows:

> Let $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_n$ be a finite collection of normal subgroups of $G$. We say that $G$ is the internal direct product of $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_n$ and write $G=H_1\times H_2\times \dots\times H_n,$ if
>
> 1. $G=H_1H_2\dotsm H_n=\{h_1h_2\dotsm h_n\mid h_i\in H_i\}$
> 2. $H_1H_2\dotsm H_i\cap H_{i+1}=\{e\}$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$

Comment: The spacing comes out better if you use `\mid` instead of `|` and `\ldots` instead of periods.

Comment: In fact, $\cdots$ ($\text{\\cdots}$) is (strongly) recommended when indicating operations rather than listing elements. If you're lazy to remember, use $\text{\\dots}$, which smartly inserts $\ldots$ or $\cdots$ based on context.

Comment: @M.Vinay In this case, I suggest `\dotsm` (dots for multiplication); just `\dots` is needed between `\times` tokens (this *is* a multiplication).

Comment: @egreg I don't think I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x \in H_i \cap H_j$ ($i < j$), then $x \in H_i \implies x \in H_1 H_2 \cdots H_{j-1}$.

**Solution:**

Let $x \in H_i \cap H_j$, for any $i \ne j$. Without loss of generality, let $i < j$.

Then, $x \in H_i \implies x \in H_1 H_2 \cdots H_{j-1}$, which further implies that $x \in H_1 H_2 \cdots H_{j-1} \cap H_j$.

But $H_1 H_2 \cdots H_{j-1} \cap H_j = \{ e \}$, and therefore, $x = e$. Thus, $H_i \cap H_j = \{ e \}$.

Comment: Oh! since $x \in H_1 H_2 \cdots H_{j-1}$ is in contradiction with the second part of the definition....isn't it? @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/152030/m-vinay

Comment: @BijeshK.S Yes, (if you assume $x \ne e$). Without the assumption, you're merely showing that every element of $H_i \cap H_j$ has to be $e$, and therefore, $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}$, directly.